# How can I use a variable taskId from viewmodel into activity

Tags: viewmodel

```
class MedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val taskRepository: TaskRepository
) : BaseViewModel() {
 private var taskId: Int = -1

fun fetchLastScannedCode() {viewModelScope.launch {
            taskRepository.fetchLastScannedTaskItems().collect { taskItems ->
                logInCrashlytics(
                    functionName = "fetchLastScannedTaskItems",
                    statusName = "TaskItems",
                    objectName = taskItems.toString()
                )

                taskItems?.let {
                    taskId = taskItems.task?.id!!
                    task = taskItems.task
                    taskItem = it.taskItemsList.firstOrNull()

}}}}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Please provide some more details about the issue you are having. It's helpful that you've posted code, but it'll be even more helpful to also provide a more specific detailed explanation :D. Please also improve your tags by adding the language and platform and any other relevant information.

Comment: After debugging, I m getting the correct value of taskId in fetchLastScannedCode() from API but it is resetting itself to -1